# Need help in copying files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement where I need to copy files with name as applicationname_IAM_YYYYMMDD.txt to a destination folder. I also need to clear all the files present in destination folder before scheduling the copying everyday. I written below code but how do I accompany the next step i.e. copying 14 files (according to current date folder) and paste to destination folder.

```
$path="\\pgb1-p-file-002\EMT_SCHD_PRD_01\UAR\Archive"
$NoOfDirs=Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
ForEach($dir in $NoOfDirs )
{
Get-ChildItem  "$path\$($dir.name)" -Recurse |
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -gt ([DateTime]::Now.Adddays(-1))) -and ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $False) } |
Select-Object @{l='Folder';e={$dir.Name}},Name,LastWriteTime |
Sort-Object  -pro LastWriteTime -Descending |
Select -First 28
}
```

Output of which is below:

```
Folder   Name                                   LastWriteTime
------   ----                                   -------------
20200729 STRUMS_IAM_20200729.txt                29/07/2020 08:08:26
20200729 PANACEA_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt           29/07/2020 08:00:02
20200729 PANACEA_IAM_20200729.txt               29/07/2020 08:00:02
20200729 UTILISOFT_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt         29/07/2020 05:33:45
20200729 UTILISOFT_IAM_20200729.txt             29/07/2020 05:33:45
20200729 ENOM_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt              29/07/2020 05:33:27
20200729 ENOM_IAM_20200729.txt                  29/07/2020 05:33:27
20200729 EARTH_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt             29/07/2020 05:33:09
20200729 EARTH_IAM_20200729.txt                 29/07/2020 05:33:08
20200729 DATAGENIC_IAM_20200729.txt             29/07/2020 05:32:44
20200729 DATAGENIC_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt         29/07/2020 05:32:43
20200729 EOS_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt               29/07/2020 05:32:18
20200729 EOS_IAM_20200729.txt                   29/07/2020 05:32:16
20200729 EURORUNNER_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt        29/07/2020 05:32:01
20200729 EURORUNNER_IAM_20200729.txt            29/07/2020 05:32:01
20200729 CODERUNNER_BGT_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt    29/07/2020 05:31:41
20200729 CODERUNNER_BGT_IAM_20200729.txt        29/07/2020 05:31:39
20200729 CODERUNNER_ACCORD_IAM_20200729.txt     29/07/2020 05:31:16
20200729 CODERUNNER_ACCORD_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt 29/07/2020 05:31:15
20200729 CUBELOGIC_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt         29/07/2020 05:30:59
20200729 CUBELOGIC_IAM_20200729.txt             29/07/2020 05:30:58
20200729 ENDUR_GRP_IAM_20200729.txt             29/07/2020 05:30:45
20200729 ENDUR_IAM_20200729.txt                 29/07/2020 05:30:40
```

From this I need to only copy and paste applicationname_IAM_YYYYMMDD to a destination folder.

Comment: use regular expressions (regex) to find the file which match your pattern and then you can move them

Comment: This is unclear.. Your description talks about _copying 14 files_, but your code selects 28. Also, what version of PowerShell are you using? As tip: do `[DateTime]::Now.Adddays(-1).Date` to get the starting date as of midnight, otherwise you will use the current time when the code runs, so you will miss out on files just before that time yesterday..